# google protocol buffers - encode in C++, decode in Java - InvalidProtocolBufferException

Tags: java, c++, protocol-buffers

Sorry, but I think I am going mad. I have this in C++:

```
std::stringstream message;
protoMsg.SerializeToOstream(&message);
boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
std::cout << "Writing response to socket. Byte size " << protoMsg.ByteSize() << " Buffer " << message.str().length() << std::endl;
for(int i(0);i<(int)message.str().length();i++)
    std::cout << (int)message.str().at(i);
std::cout << std::endl;
boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(message.str()), ignored_error);
std::cout << "Done writing." << std::endl;
```

Which yields this output

```
Writing response to socket. Byte size 88 Buffer 88
1886811891161111001113278971091012500000000320400480560640730000000081000000008859621061211611110011132115121109789710910111416691201161011141109710832114101113117101115116
Done writing.
```

And this in Java:

```
try {
  System.out.println("Parsing");
  int lenbytes = is.read(buffer);
  System.out.println("Read bytes " + lenbytes);
  for(int i=0;i<lenbytes;i++)
    System.out.print(Integer.toString((int)buffer[i]));
  System.out.println("");
  EnvInfoProto envInfoProto = EnvInfoProto.parseFrom(buffer);
  System.out.println("Done");
  return envInfoProto;
} catch(IOException ignore) { System.out.println("Ex: " + ignore.toString(); }
```

Which yields

```
Parsing
Read bytes 88
1886811891161111001113278971091012500000000320400480560640730000000081000000008859621061211611110011132115121109789710910111416691201161011141109710832114101113117101115116
Ex: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).
```

The binary data is the same. I checked that I am using the right version of the proto files. I am a bit at a loss tbh. Any help appreciated.

Comment: One point to note around your title: using Protocol Buffers does *not* count as encryption, and shouldn't be mistaken for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking the message to be parsed from the *whole* of `buffer` - and my guess is that `buffer` is more than 88 bytes long.

I can't remember offhand whether `parseFrom` allows you to specify the maximum amount of data to read, but an alternative would be:

```
ByteArrayIntputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer, 0, lenbytes);
EnvInfoProto envInfoProto = EnvInfoProto.parseFrom(stream);
```

Note that this still has the problem that you're *assuming* you can read all the data from the stream in a single call to `read`, which is never a good idea - but that's a very separate issue. If you're going to close the socket after writing, you could just parse stream from the  socket's `InputStream` in the Java code, of course. If you're *not* going to close the stream, I would suggest writing the message length to the socket first (as a 32-bit integer) so you can then read that in Java, and read exactly the right amount of data, knowing when you're finished.